# Is it possible to set a system path as spring context

Tags: spring, annotations, applicationcontext

I want to load my Spring application context via annotations like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:/path/to/spring-context1.xml", "file:/path/to/spring-context2.xml"})
```

I am trying this because the context file is not in my classpath.
I've read several times that this was possible but it does not seem to work.
So my question is: "Is this really possible and am I doing something wrong?

I've got another question if this happens to be possible: if I want to use a relative path instead of an absolute one, from where should it be relative? From the pom.xml location?

Comment: OK, seems that the problem is located on my side of the keyboard ;)

I've got my answers :
    * Yes it is possible
    * If you want to set a relative path, it has to be relative to (from? excuse my english) the pom location.

The error I was making was so stupid, I won't explain it.

Comment: I guess I have to mark my post as "_resolved_" but I can not find how.

Comment: In order to mark the post as resolved, you have to write an answer for it, and then you cann accept this answers (check mark symbol at the left)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments of my first post, the problem came from me ;)
So the answers are :

- yes, you can use the "file:" prefix to set your Spring context
- yes, you can use relative path, relative to the pom.xml directory

Hope this helps.